# Why is a blank page appearing when I submit my form?

Tags: html, forms, attributes, local-storage

When I submit my form, a blank page appears. I want to stay on the same page.

HTML:

```
<form id='credentials'>
     <div class="field">
          <label for="name">Username:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="username" />
     </div>
     <div class="field">
          <button type="submit">Send</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
if (localStorage) {  // checks for localStorage support
    // add event listener for form submission
        document.getElementById('credentials').addEventListener('submit', function() {
            // get value of username field
            var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
            console.log('submitted')
            // save name in localStorage
            localStorage.setItem('name', username);
        });
} else {
    console.log('no localStorage');
}
```

Comment: `return false;` in the submit event listener should do the trick

Comment: You don't seem to have an element with the id `username`

Comment: Apart from the typo, nope. Can you set up a test case, say at http://jsfiddle.net? (I think SO has built-in support for this too, now, but to be honest I don't know how it works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I used `return false;` in the submit event listener, but then I read an article that said such usage of `return false;` is so widely misused, since it appears to be doing what we want. In reality, it places restrictions on your code, reducing its flexibility, increasing the difficulty of maintaining it.

The article: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

I successfully used `event.preventDefault()` in the submit event listener to prevent the form from being submitted.